# What's the difference between org.w3c.dom.Node and Node in Java?

Tags: java, xmlnode

I program in Java and I'm using a DOM parser.

I noticed that there is a difference between

```
org.w3c.dom.Node
```

and

```
Node
```

but i don't know what that difference is.

I figured that out when i tried to call a method which had an argument of type:
**org.w3c.dom.Node** .

I entered a **Node argument** and i took the following **error:**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.Node
at elementchildren.ElementChildren.main(ElementChildren.java:50)
Java Result: 1
```

May you please help me?

Comment: `Node` is not the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you've accidentally used

```
import javax.xml.soap.Node;
```

instead of

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
```

A [`DeferredTextImpl`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredTextImpl.html) instance implements the latter, not the former.

Comment: Yes you are right about it, i had also imported the 
"javax.xml.soap.Node;" but i removed it now,thanks